# Zoom in images with their layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to zoom in to a specific point on screen. I have a layout containing child image views. Scaling layout is working great but the problem is in content images; when I click one of them, after scale layout, it triggers click of another image. The positions of the images are still the same so the onclick trigger is not scaled. How can I scale layout with its image children simultaneously?

This is my scale code:

```
ScaleAnimation zoomInAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1, 2f, 1, 2f, zoomX, zoomY);
subcategoryLayout.startAnimation(zoomInAnimation);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I properly understand your question, but it sounds as if you are not filling the elements after the animation ends. You might try using [setFillAfter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter(boolean))

Comment: No i put it  , my question is why content images are not zoomed physically , i searched and found that scale layout zoom in drawing of child view but not view itself , so that images inside layout appear they are zoomed but view itself with its click listener still in same position , my question how to move view while scaling layout?